# PHP assign each multiple uploaded files to variable

Tags: php, file-upload, explode

How can I separate multiple uploaded files ($new_file_name) out of foreach loop for sql query process? How to assign each files to its variable?

```
// manipulate uploaded images
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

        $file_name = $key.'_'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        //explode fine name and extension
        $ext_x = explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext_x));
        $file_name = str_replace('.'.$ext, '', $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);

        //new file name
        $output_dir = '../items/'.$list_id;
        $new_file_name = rand(1, 999999).'.'.$ext;
        $pathfile = $output_dir.'/'.$new_file_name;

        // create directory if does not exist
        if(is_dir($output_dir) == false){
            mkdir($output_dir, 0700);
        }

        if(is_dir($pathfile) == false){

            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $pathfile)){

                //resize original image
                WideImage::load($pathfile)->resize(300, 400)->saveToFile($pathfile);

                //generate thumbnail
                $split = explode('.', $new_file_name);
                $thumb = $split[0].'_t.'.$split[1];

                WideImage::load($pathfile)->resize(70, 70)->saveToFile($output_dir.'/'.$thumb);
            }

        }

    }

}

//here I needed to get each of the uploaded images to update database (max 3 images)

//how to explode above $new_file_name into variable here?
$new_file_name1 = $new_file_name[0]; //and so on...

$q = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `listing` SET image1='".$new_file_name1."', image2='".$new_file_name2."', image3='".$new_file_name3."', thumbnail='".$thumb1."', WHERE list_id='".$list_id."' AND user_id='".$user_id."'") or die($mysqli->error);
```

I can get each of the file by

```
$var0 = $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
$var1 = $_FILES['files']['name'][1];
$var2 = $_FILES['files']['name'][2];
```

but I can't

```
$var0 = $new_file_name[0];
$var1 = $new_file_name[1];
$var2 = $new_file_name[2];
```

Thanks for advise!

Comment: I 'm not sure what you are asking here. `$new_file_name = $_FILES['files']['name']`, while kind of pointless, would enable the suggested syntax.

Comment: Perhaps if you actually an array of the filenames you're generating, because right now you keep re-using `$pathfile` on every iteration and DESTROYING the filename from the previous iterations

Comment: my purpose is to assign each $new_file_name to variable in order for update database its column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to set the name:

```
$new_file_name[] = rand(1, 999999).'.'.$ext;
```

and inside the for loop use:

```
end($new_file_name)
```

for the current file. E.g:

```
    $pathfile = $output_dir.'/'.end($new_file_name);
```

The problem you are having is because in every iteration through the loop you setup the `$new_file_name` to a new random string. By using `$new_file_name[]` you are adding an element to `$new_file_name` which is then becoming an array. Using the `end()` functions returns the last element of the array so in the current iteration of the loop it will return the last added random string which corresponds to your current file;

**EDIT:**

```
// manipulate uploaded images
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

    $file_name = $key.'_'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

    //explode fine name and extension
    $ext_x = explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
    $ext = strtolower(end($ext_x));
    $file_name = str_replace('.'.$ext, '', $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);

    //new file name
    $output_dir = '../items/'.$list_id;
    $new_file_name[] = rand(1, 999999).'.'.$ext;
    $pathfile = $output_dir.'/'.end($new_file_name);

    // create directory if does not exist
    if(is_dir($output_dir) == false){
        mkdir($output_dir, 0700);
    }

    if(is_dir($pathfile) == false){

        if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $pathfile)){

            //resize original image
            WideImage::load($pathfile)->resize(300, 400)->saveToFile($pathfile);

            //generate thumbnail
            $split = explode('.', end($new_file_name));
            $thumb = $split[0].'_t.'.$split[1];

            WideImage::load($pathfile)->resize(70, 70)->saveToFile($output_dir.'/'.$thumb);
        }

    }

}

}

//Getting the variables
$new_file_name1 = $new_file_name[0]; //and so on...

$q = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `listing` SET image1='".$new_file_name1."', image2='".$new_file_name2."', image3='".$new_file_name3."', thumbnail='".$thumb1."', WHERE list_id='".$list_id."' AND user_id='".$user_id."'") or die($mysqli->error);
```

You could also use: `$new_file_name[0]` inside the SQL query.

Comment: did you means I have to add a for loop? I get error when replaced with `$pathfile = $output_dir.'/'.end($new_file_name);` -> `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\...`, could you provide an example code?

Comment: You have to change `$new_file_name` to `end($new_file_name)` everywhere in the for loop. I'll update my answer with the code fixed.